# Office, Forefront and whatever else I find

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[microsoft-office-2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2010) -> [ms-office-2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-office-2010)
[microsoft-office](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office) -> [ms-office](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-office)

[microsoft-access](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-access) -> [ms-access](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-access)

[threat-management-gateway](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/threat-management-gateway) -> [ms-ftmg](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-ftmg)
[tmg-2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tmg-2010) -> [ms-ftmg-2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-ftmg-2010)
[forefront](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/forefront) -> [ms-forefront](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-forefront)
[forefront-2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/forefront-2010) -> [ms-forefront](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-forefront)

[msvirtualserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/msvirtualserver) -> [ms-virtualserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-virtualserver)

Burninate: [microsoft-virtualization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-virtualization)

Comment: ...I ran into these a couple weeks ago when mobile, and mentally flagged them for dealing when I had time. Then forgot the tag-set. I'll get on it.

Answer (score 4):

These have been done, except for the burninations. One was already a synonym.

The tag [ms](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms) should be burninated since bad-taggers are attempting to enter "ms sql" into the tag field with predictable results.